# How to, at the time of installation setup, check the serial key?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I have a project in C#. I want to create a setup and deploy it. I want to check the serial key at the time of installation setup , which is valid or not (like when we installing the license copy of the MS office. It asks serial key. If this serial key is valid, then this software will install successfully). How can I add the serial key and rollback setup process if serial key is not valid?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Here you have described by Scott Guthrie how to make installation setup with custom actions.

[Tip/Trick: Creating Packaged ASP.NET Setup Programs with VS 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx)

You can customize this example to your needs.

Comment: what is the use of content file. Because my application is windows application

Comment: Use the dialog to get the serial key(Like how he got connection string).
then read the key through your code and check if it is valid or not(He has shown a code to update web.config)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to given link, you will b able to a setup with serial key.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/easysetup.aspx

By: Gourav Pal, BuckSoftech Pvt. Ltd., Ranchi